# SignalR ASPNetHost does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, mono, signalr

I've downloaded the latest SignalR code (as of 04/04/12) from [GitHub](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) as it now compiles with MonoDevelop so I can use it on OS X.

But while testing the new version with the [SignalR.Sample](http://nuget.org/packages/SignalR.Sample) example listed on the [Getting Started](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/introduction-to-signalr) page, it fails with the following error:

The name 'AspNetHost' does not exist in the current context

This occurs in StockTicker.cs here:

```
private static dynamic GetClients()
{
    return AspNetHost.DependencyResolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>().GetClients<StockTickerHub>();
}
```

Can anyone explain what has become of AspNetHost?

Suggestions on how to get the SignalR.Sample compiling would be very welcome.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem and found that this was deprecated in SignalR 0.5. Here is an [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2012/05/04/api-improvements-made-in-signalr-0-5.aspx) detailing the changes.

Specific to your item, the change is from this:

```
public void PerformLongRunningHubOperation()
{
    var clients = AspNetHost.DependencyResolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>().GetClients<MyHub>();

    clients.notify("Hello world");
}
```

To  this in 0.5:

```
public void PerformLongRunningHubOperation()
{
    IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();

    context.Clients.notify("Hello world");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna need to read the code because the source isn't in sync with the docs. The docs are for the current release, not the actively developed.

Take a look at the asp.net sample to see the current API. It's not set in stone yet though.

Comment: Same error occurs with VS11, New ASP.Net MVC 4 Empty Project, install-package SignalR.Sample 0.2.1.

Comment: The docs were updated. Please refer to https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki for updated API.